# hciconfig -a Connection timed out (110) , bluez, btusb - Bluetooth Not Working

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I am experiencing this issue on my raspberry pi.

After a while of my python program running, it seems like one (or more) of the bluetooth adapters will "lock up" and hciconfig -a will output:
: **Connection timed out (110)**

```
root ~ # hciconfig -a
hci3:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 5C:F3:70:61:CA:D6  ACL MTU: 9000:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING 
    RX bytes:5315773 acl:178107 sco:0 events:287995 errors:0
    TX bytes:487424645 acl:527773 sco:0 commands:13454 errors:0
    Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
Can't read local name on hci3: Connection timed out (110)
```

The problem seems to manifest more frequently when multiple adapters are used.

The project I am working on involves using multiple (and sometimes single) USB bluetooth adapters to obex-push files to phones.
The python program that does the following things:

1.automatically detects adapters - **#hciconfig -a**
2.configures them - **#hciconfig  CMD**
3.Inquires devices - **#hcitool -i  inq**
4.Obex push files on  (possibly simultaneously with other threads and other ) - **bluez dbus**

Some info from my system:

```
root ~ # modinfo btusb
filename:       /lib/modules/3.12.29-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko.gz
license:        GPL
version:        0.6
description:    Generic Bluetooth USB driver ver 0.6
author:         Marcel Holtmann <marcel@holtmann.org>
srcversion:     61D6539530170376DCAF49C
alias:          usb:v*p*d*dcE0dsc01dp01ic*isc*ip*in*
...
depends:        bluetooth
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.12.29-1-ARCH preempt mod_unload modversions ARMv6
```

...

```
root ~ # pacman -Q
...
bluez 5.24-1
bluez-utils 5.24-1
...
dbus 1.8.0-1
dbus-glib 0.102-1
...
libusb 1.0.18-1
...
linux-api-headers 3.13.2-1
linux-firmware 20140217.343e460-1
linux-raspberrypi 3.12.29-1
```

Any ideas/or suggestions?

Is there a newer version of btusb? I looked, but I came up mostly empty handed

...

PS:
These forums seem to suggest that something similar may have been fixed:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=183411
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=183038
but the referenced problem appears to be specifically with the Atheros adapter chipset and I am using Broadcom chipset. Also, it appears the latest version of linux I can get for the rpi is 13.13 headers and linux-raspberrypi 13.12